# Send JSON Object Inside MutipartFormData(FormData)

Tags: json, angular, multipartform-data

I have Formdata instance in component I use that to append my reactive form data.problem is I have an object that contains this fields `{img:File,isCover:boolean}` i want to append this to my form data.

problem is if i stringify this object the image field throws empty object `{img:{},isCover:true}`.when I dig a little bit about it. then saw if we stringify object with methods it will return an empty object

How do I overcome this.i want to send all those data in a single multipart data request.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you need to append every value of your JSON object to a formdata.

First initialize a variable in you class.

```
formData = new FormData()
```

Then in your function append every json object.

```
this.formData.appen("yourKey", JSON.Object.Value)
```

It's kind of tedious though... You can , depending on your backend, nest all of the plain text objects in your JSON to a long string and append that to a FormData and call the key "JSON" for instance. And the append the image to the FormData with the key "Image".

After that you can in your API Backend get just the JSON stingified object with the key JSON and do something else with the image by getting it with the key "Image".